# Optimize C code for ARM Cortex A53 (using RPi 3B+ for debugging)?

Tags: pi-3b+, windows, debug

I need to debug (and possibly verify, profile and optimize) some audio algorithms for Arm Cortex A53. The algorithms take input from file as PCM samples, and also drop the output the same way, as PCM samples.

I am not sure which way to go regarding my main goal: debug this C code on Arm Cortex A53 (I have recently purchased a RPi 3B+ board for this).

I have a problem with the concept that RPi already has an OS installed on it, so it is not a regular development board.

What is the easiest way to set-up my development process? Which OS? Which software do I need? Do I need JTAG? How do I connect?

My usual setup on a PC is Windows + Eclipse + GCC toolchain.

Comment: How exactly is an OS a problem?

Comment: Maybe it isn't a problem at all, I just need to get used to the idea. On the other hand, I'd like to have a clean way of measuring performance, to profile and validate simple clean and isolated algorithms, to measure MIPS count, etc... OS to me just seems like something I don't need, something that will add to the confusion. Will it help anyhow?

Comment: "Will it help anyhow?" - For one, the OS will protect system memory if your algorithm starts using garbage as pointers, and it will support tools like valgrind which detect memory leaks and thread interlocks.

Comment: "clean way of measuring performance" - how clean you need it to be? Suppose the OS has 5% overhead and your performance measurement shows a 5% error, is that a problem?

Comment: *"the concept that RPi already has an OS installed on it"* -> No, there is no where for it to be installed.  Some distributors do sell Pis bundled with an SD card containing either RpiOS/Raspbian or NOOBS, but these are not required, there are other options, etc.

Comment: Hmmm: https://metebalci.com/blog/bare-metal-raspberry-pi-3b-jtag/